# How to keep application up-to-date that is dependet on the content of a website?

Tags: c#, web-crawler, html-agility-pack

I currently have following "problem": I gather some HTML via the C# Webclient-Class and traverese it with the HtmlAgilityPack. (The Website doesn't offer a Web API)

If anything on the website changes I have a big problem. For example if a class name of a div changes because I can't read the value anymore.

My application will still work without the data but it will be almost useless.

So what can I do to ensure that my application is always Up-To-Date to changes to the website?

My idea would be to create Unit-Tests for every HTML-Node that I use. A build-server could run these Unit-Tests every hour and inform me if an HTML-Node can't be found anymore. If it fails I can adapt my application and release an update.

Is that really all I can do?

Comment: Why release a new updated application when you could make a product that can adapt to the changes? Why not figure out some sort of map (perhaps a bunch of [CSS selectors](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Fizzler.Systems.HtmlAgilityPack/) that relate to the values you need to extract) that could be served by you? Then your crawler application would start by ensuring that the "map" is up to date by downloading the latest version from your server. Going through a whole release cycle to make such changes seems very long-winded.

Comment: That is actually a good idea. Of course I agree with you that going through a whole release cycle would be a little bit too much. I'm still in development so this is not what I'm doing right now. I just wanted to ask this question so I can get a better solution when I actually come to this point. Sadly the website doesn't offer unique ids or CSS selectors but I think a good alternative would be to save the XPATH in a mapping-file.